# How to add a Python library to IntelliJ?

Tags: python, intellij-idea, ide

I have the following library: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/RPi.GPIO

I wish to add it to IntelliJ so I get autocomplete support. 
However I can't see to find an option to add a library.

I tried Project Structure > Dependencies > + > Library > New Library

But that just gives me options for a New Library for "Java", "From Marven" and "Scala", but NOT Python.

Note: I do have the Python IntelliJ plugin installed and I created this project by clicking a new Python Project within IntelliJ.

Comment: You should be able to install that package using pip. From there, you just need to make sure that your IntelliJ project is pointing to that Python interpreter. Are you working from a virtualenv?

Comment: No not working on virtual environment. How do I use PIP?

Comment: OK. I suggest you do the following. It will help greatly. Read how to use [pip](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/python-pip-usage). Then learn how to use [virtualenvironments](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/). From there, learn how to set up your project using [setup](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html). This will allow you properly package your application to include all your package dependancies. From there, once you get the hang of those, you just need to look on IntelliJ help pages to connect to a virtualenv.

Comment: it worked fine. Still bit odd that my other way didn't work. Anyways, put your comment as an answer and I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you do the following, it will help greatly.

1. Read how to use [pip](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/python-pip-usage).
2. Then learn how to use [virtualenvironments](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/).
3. Then, learn how to set up your project using [setup](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html). This will allow you properly package your application to include all your package dependancies.
4. From there, once you get the hang of those, you just need to look on IntelliJ help pages to connect to a virtualenv.